# How to build & distribute binary framework for both devices and simulater Xcode 10.2?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, frameworks, xcode10.2

I have a framework in Swift that needs to be used in both Swift and ObjC apps.

In Xcode 10.2 the generated `MyFramework-Swift.h` no longer contains definitions for simulator as is reported [here](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/2718).

Carthage has solved this internally.

How should I solve this in my framework's Xcode project?